# Select text containing tag with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I need to select text containing an `<a>` tag with xpath but I can't figure out the right way to do this. The result should be "Image Caption And A Link." and the anchor link should be preserved.

```
<p class="caption"><img src="..."> 
Image Caption <a href="...">And A Link</a>.
</p>
```

The last expression I tried was following,

```
//*[preceding-sibling::img]
```

but no matter how I do it, I either just select the outer or just the text from from the `<a>` tag.

Comment: What kind of XPath result do you want, which XPath API do you use? You say you "need to select text" and the result should be "Image Caption And A Link" which is a plain string, but you also say the "anchor link should be preserved", which sounds as you there don't want a string but rather the `a` element node returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select what is not there. `"Image Caption And A Link."` does not exist in this HTML.

```
<p class="caption"><img src="..."> 
Image Caption <a href="...">And A Link</a>.
</p>
```

The best you can get is a list of separate nodes - it looks like you want all nodes inside a `p.caption` except when it's an `img`. This would work:

```
//p[contains(@class, 'caption')]/node()[not(self::img)]
```

and return three nodes:

```
['\nImage Caption ', <a href="...">And A Link</a>, '.\n']
```

---

To guard against matching false positives in CSS classes due to partial matches, use

```
//p[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' caption ')]
```